# Проверка дат c#

Tags: c#, база-данных, datagridview

На форме есть datagridview, который заполняется из access. В этой таблице есть несколько столбцов и неограниченное кол-во строк. Из этой таблицы мне нужно как то брать все даты из столбца "ДатаОкончания" и сравнивать их с настоящей датой, если Настоящая дата больше выводить сообщение. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: А почему вы не хотите SQL запросом обратиться к БД? В SQL есть замечательная функция `MAX`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) //перебираем все строки в таблице
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells) //перебираем все ячейки в каждой строке
            {
                if (cell.ColumnIndex == 2) //проверяем какому столбцу принадлежит ячейка (указать индекс вашего столбца)
                {
                    DateTime DataGridValue = Convert.ToDateTime(cell.Value); // преобразовываем значение ячейки в тип данных DateTime
                    if (DataGridValue < DateTime.Now) //сравниваем значение из ячейки и текущую дату
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Текущая дата больше");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Текущая дата меньше");

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```